# Now Playing window in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, itunes

I was wondering how I would go about making a script using the Script Utility that, when clicked, would return a window that shows the Song name and Artist of whatever is playing in iTunes. Very new to AppleScript and have spent an unsuccessful hour trying to make it work!

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `current track` property:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    tell current track to artist & " - " & name
    display dialog result
    --do shell script "terminal-notifier -message '' -title " & quoted form of result
end tell
```

If you need to update the window continuously, using something like GeekTool might be a better option.